# Connection error except with SQLYog

Tags: mysql, connectivity

I have a problem connecting with the database with PHP or with MySQL in Linux . I can only connect to the DB with SQLYog. The error I'm getting is this:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XX.XX.XX.XX' (110)
```

What can be the problem? The IP from the computer of the SQLYog and the computer with PHP or MySQL in Linux is the same.

Edit: The MySQL Server is not in the same network where I'm developing. This MySQL server is from another company.

Comment: When connect to MySQL, please use `localhost` as hostname, `root` as username and nothing in password parameter. please add the code in your question. Also, add the result of `select host,user,password from user;`

Comment: I can't use localhost as hostname because the mysql server is from another company and isn't in our network

Comment: If `PHP` and `MySQL` both are on same computer, you can use `localhost`.

Comment: I know.. but they aren't on the same computer

Comment: As you told, you are also not able to connect database from linux terminal. How are you connecting `mysql database` from `linux`?

Comment: mysql -u user -p 33112 -h XX.XX.XX.XX dbname

Comment: mysql -uroot -p<pass> -h<hostname/ip> -P<port>...what error you see using this command on command line prompt?

Comment: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XX.XX.XX.XX' (110)

Comment: Do you have access to configuration file and log and error files? If not, If this database provided to you by web hosting company, you can raise this concern to them.

Comment: I don't have access. I set up xampp on my computer and i can connect with php . May be it is problem with mysql driver?

Comment: Since, you haven't access, you need to raise your concern with your service provider(hosting company). They will surely help you.

Comment: The problem was with the provider. They only gave to the mysql to my IP not the web server. Thanks to all!